# Errors converting to date-time in snowflake with the T delimiter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I am trying to convert to timestamp with the `T` delimiter. I have looked at examples but I seem to be getting errors. I am not sure what I am getting wrong

My code :

```
select Id,
     to_timestamp_ntz(dt."Value",'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
    from Accounts
```

Errors

```
Can't parse '2018-09-08 07:40:45' as timestamp with format 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the timestamp format you want the input timestamp should look like **'2018-09-08T07:40:45'**, yours is missing the T.

So this works:

```
select to_timestamp_ntz('2018-09-08T07:40:45','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

I get:

```
2018-09-08 07:40:45.000
```

or otherwise use for that input timestamp the format:

```
select to_timestamp_ntz('2018-09-08 07:40:45','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

which gives same output.

Answer (score 0):

You command is doing an **input formatting** which means that you're saying that `2018-09-08 07:40:45` is in format `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS` which is not true because you are missing the `T` between the date and time in your input.

If you'd like to do an **output formatting** you would use TO_CHAR instead.

E.g.

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('2018-09-08 07:40:45'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

Returns:

```
2018-09-08T07:40:45
```

Comment: This looks good but I want the output to be in time stamp please and not char